# PowerShell DataTable delete column containing value "description"

Tags: powershell, datatable

I would like to delete all empty rows from the DataTable below as well as delete the column containing the value "description".  I am able to delete all empty rows; however, I can't figure out how to also explicitly delete `description` from the DataTable.

**Original DataTable:**

```xml
dev_id              : 4721
office_id           : 355
name                : Bobby
ip                  : 10.10.10.1
ipv6                : 2001:1930:ff28:ff00::1
mac                 :
serial_num          : XX234555
platform            : Supercode
                    :
description         : I;need;to;delete;this;
                    :  
                    : 
max_speed           : 100000
```

**Code:**

```PoSH
$myreader = $mycommand.ExecuteReader()
$DevicesDataTable.Load($myreader)
$myconnection.Close()

$Columns = $DevicesDataTable.Columns.Count
$Rows    = $DevicesDataTable.Rows.Count

for ($r = 0; $r -lt $Rows; $r++) {    
    $Empty = 0
    for ($c = 0; $c -lt $Columns; $c++) {

        if (($DevicesDataTable.Rows[$r].IsNull($c)) -or ($DevicesDataTable.Rows[$r].Equals("description"))) {
            $Empty++
        }
    }
    if ($Empty -eq $Columns) {
        $DevicesDataTable.Rows[$r].Delete()
    }
}
# Delete
$DevicesDataTable.AcceptChanges()

Write-Output $DevicesDataTable
```

**Result:**
*Note DataTable below still shows `description`*:

```xml
dev_id              : 4721
office_id           : 355
name                : Bobby
ip                  : 10.10.10.1
ipv6                : 2001:1930:ff28:ff00::1
serial_num          : XX234555
platform            : Supercode
description         : I;need;to;delete;this;
max_speed           : 100000
```

**Note:**  I am able to identify the column containing "description", however, I'm not sure how to delete the respective row via the correct method:

```
if ($DevicesDataTable.Columns[$c].ColumnName.Equals("description"))
```

Comment: Please clarify your intent: Are you trying to unconditionally remove the _column_ named `description` from the table as a whole?

Comment: Yes. I dont want 'description' to be in the modified datatable. I want it unconditionally removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop a column from the data table by calling `Remove()` on the `Columns` collection:

```
$DevicesDataTable.Columns.Remove('description')
```